# Where are the modules installed using luarocks

Tags: lua, luarocks

I am trying to require a module I downloaded using luarocks using

```
require "lualogging"
```

but lua (and I!) cannot find where this module was downloaded to. Here is what I did

I have used apt-get to install luarocks, and then I ran

```
sudo luarocks install lualogging
```

I then ran

```
luarocks list
```

and received the following output

```
Installed rocks:

lualogging
1.3.0-1 (installed) - /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks

luasocket
3.0rc1-1 (installed) - /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks
```

Natural this led me to believe that lualogging was located in /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks, but running this command

```
find /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks "lualogging.lua"
```

returned nothing. What am I doing wrong here? This may be related, but I cannot find what my LUA_PATH environment variable is so it may be that it was never set? I'd like to be able to run require "lualogging" from any file regardless of where it is located in the filesystem, and then log to my heart's content. But I can't even find where lualogging.lua exists...

Comment: It might be `lualogging/init.lua`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I managed to stumble upon it in /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lualogging.lua. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 10):

Run `luarocks show lualogging`. It will list all modules and where they are.

Answer (score 2):

It should be 
`require "logging"` 
not 
`require "lualogging"`

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the one provided by luarocks: [rock tree](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Rocks-repositories)

This document gives the directory structure of luarocks. However, the location of the base directory is not mentioned.

The location of the base directory is not the same on different systems and under different conditions.
On Unix/Linux/MacOS it is `/usr/local` by default, but there is a special case, I don't know if it is a bug or intentional by luarocks, so please refer to this issue:[Inconsistent behaviour when executing luarocks in different directories](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/issues/1526)

Comment: Not relevant because this doesn't say where the base is

Comment: @ReinstateMonica3167040 Already replenished